# Create a proper textbox after the :before selector for CSS

Tags: css, textbox, alignment, selector

**Objective:**
To make the text start where the first line started underneath it.




**Recommended Language:** CSS and HTML


**Example:**
[image: Example]

**Final Result:**
[image]

Comment: No, we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: make a fiddle or codepen with your code and show some of your test

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Homework and shows no prior effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `display: block;` to the :before selector.

```
p:before {
    content: "This is inside the boxd and in the :before selector";
    background: green;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4XY2R/

Assuming this is what you're trying to do.